# suporting .rm audio formats in iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio, rm

I need to design a application that supports the streaming of .rm audio from the server.

But from the api docs of apple it seems that .rm is not supported in iPhone. 
Is there any other way to implement this .... ???

Best Regards,

Mohammed Sadiq .

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone : play rm files on iphone programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617207/iphone-play-rm-files-on-iphone-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

When the built-in SDK doesn't provide support, the only option is to roll your own codec and play!

Check audio units if you are motivated to do that!

Comment: Hi,
     Is there any link/tutorials available to roll down the codec to support .rm audio files in iPhone.