# iphone : play rm files on iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, rm

i have a good experince with playing audio in general on iphone but i would like to have a way to play .RM files on iphone app .. i've tried the normal approach put it didn't give me any sound at all ..

so any help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to convert these RealMedia files into a more modern format before you can play them.

Comment: Plenty of those online. ffmpeg is a good command-line tool, if you're into that.

Answer (score 1):

You could learn the file format and write your own decoder and obtain the pcm data, or whatever format you want the samples in, and then feed that to either AudioQueues or AudioUnits.